# Issues with GUI on a permutation/combination calculator

Tags: java, swing, combinations, permutation, joptionpane

I was able to program this, and I don't have any errors that I can see, and it even displays the gui.  I'm pretty sure I assigned the buttons properly. But the GUI is temperamental, and when I run it, it displays but sometimes the insides of the gui disappear when I enter values.  But it calculates nCr, just not pCr.

I have a driver class.  Pretty sure it's implemented properly.  Here's my panel class.  I'm wondering what's wrong and why the GUI doesn't function properly

I realize this is  a lot of code.  I'm not expecting anyone to rewrite this for me.  I just want to know what I'm doing wrong, and how I can go about correcting it.

Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;





public class PermCombCalc extends JPanel {
    JButton permButton = new JButton();
    JButton combButton = new JButton();
    JButton clearButton = new JButton();

    JTextField npermField = new JTextField();
    JTextField rperField = new JTextField();
    JTextField nchooseField = new JTextField();
    JTextField rchooseField = new JTextField();

    JTextField pAnswerField = new JTextField();
    JTextField cAnswerField = new JTextField();




    public PermCombCalc() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));

        JLabel permLabel = new JLabel("Permutation:");
        permLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 20);
        permLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        add(permLabel);

        JLabel combLabel = new JLabel("Combination:");
        combLabel.setBounds(215, 20, 75, 20);
        combLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        add(combLabel);

        // Creating Permutation Button
        JLabel PnrLabel = new JLabel("P (n,r)");
        PnrLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
        permButton.setBounds(10, 115, 100, 25);
        add(permButton);
        permButton.add(PnrLabel);
        // Action Listener for permbutton
        permButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                permButton.setActionCommand("Perm");
                permButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

            }

        });

        // Creating combination button
        JLabel CnrLabel = new JLabel("C(n, r)");
        CnrLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
        combButton.setBounds(190, 115, 100, 25);
        add(combButton);
        combButton.add(CnrLabel);
        // ActionListener
        combButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                combButton.setActionCommand("comb");
                combButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


            }
        });

        // Text fields for n and r

        npermField.setBounds(23, 50, 60, 20);
        add(npermField);
        nchooseField.setBounds(230, 50, 60, 20);
        add(nchooseField);

        rperField.setBounds(23, 80, 60, 20);
        add(rperField);
        rchooseField.setBounds(230, 80, 60, 20);
        add(rchooseField);

        // Input fields

        JLabel npLabel = new JLabel("n:");
        npLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
        npLabel.setBounds(10, 55, 10, 10);
        add(npLabel);

        JLabel ncLabel = new JLabel("n:");
        ncLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        ncLabel.setBounds(217, 55, 10, 10);
        add(ncLabel);

        JLabel rpLabel = new JLabel("r:");
        rpLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        rpLabel.setBounds(10, 85, 10, 10);
        add(rpLabel);

        JLabel rcLabel = new JLabel("r:");
        rcLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        rcLabel.setBounds(217, 85, 10, 10);
        add(rcLabel);

        // Fields for answers

        JLabel pAnswerJLabel = new JLabel("<-Answers->");
        pAnswerJLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        pAnswerJLabel.setBounds(115, 155, 74, 10);
        add(pAnswerJLabel);
        pAnswerField.setBounds(10, 150, 100, 20);
        add(pAnswerField);


        cAnswerField.setBounds(190, 150, 100, 20);  // where is this field?!
        add(cAnswerField);

        // Buttons

        //clearButton.setBounds(10, 210, 110, 25);
        //add(clearButton);

        //JLabel clearLabel = new JLabel("Clear Fields");
        //clearLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        //clearButton.add(clearLabel);
        // clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        // public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // clearButton.setActionCommand("Clear");

    }
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("perm")) {
            // contentPane.setBackground(Color.red);
            long Pnr = Permutation();
            if (Pnr != 0) {
                pAnswerField.setText(Pnr + "");
            }
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comb")) {
            // contentPane.setBackground(Color.black);
            long Cnr = Combination();
            if (Cnr != 0) {
                cAnswerField.setText(Cnr + "");

            }
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Clear")) {
            // contentPane.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            npermField.setText(null);
            rperField.setText(null);
            pAnswerField.setText(null);
            nchooseField.setText(null);
            rchooseField.setText(null);
            cAnswerField.setText(null);
        }

    }

    public long Permutation() {
        String npString = npermField.getText();
        String rpString = rperField.getText();
        int npint = 0;
        int rpint = 0;

        try {
            npint = Integer.parseInt(npString);
            rpint = Integer.parseInt(rpString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR! The values for 'n' and 'r' \n must be positive integers");
            return 0;
        }
        if (npint <= 0 || rpint <= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR! The values for 'n' and 'r' \n must be positive integers");
            return 0;
        }
        if (npint < rpint) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR! The value of 'r' must be less than \n or equal to the value of 'n.'");
            return 0;
        }

        long Pnr = 1;
        int mult = npint;
        int nmr = (npint - rpint);
        while (mult > nmr) {
            Pnr = Pnr * mult;
            mult--;
        }

        return Pnr;
    }

    public long Combination()  {
        String ncString = nchooseField.getText();
        String rcString = rchooseField.getText();
        int ncint = 0;
        int rcint = 0;

        try {
            ncint = Integer.parseInt(ncString);
            rcint = Integer.parseInt(rcString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR! The values for 'n' and 'r' \n must be positive integers");
            return 0;
        }
        if (ncint <= 0 || rcint <= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! The values for 'n' and 'r' \n must be positive integers");
            return 0;
        }
        if (ncint < rcint) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR! The value of 'r' must be less than \n or equal to the value of 'n.'");
            return 0;
        }

        long nfact = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= ncint; i++) {
            nfact = nfact * i;
        }
        long rfact = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= rcint; i++) {
            rfact = rfact * i;
        }
        long nmr = ncint - rcint;
        int nmrfact = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= nmr; i++) {
            nmrfact = nmrfact * i;
        }

        long Cnr = (nfact / (rfact * nmrfact));

        return Cnr;

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), but you aren't actually specifying the placements of your components, so they are being rendered in unexpected places.

Here is a screenshot of your application with an orange border around `pAnswerField` and a red border around `cAnswerField`

[image]

You should take a look at the [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for help on using the Layout Managers properly.

For your application, [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is probably a resonable balance between complexity and layout flexibility

[GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) will give you the most flexibility, but they can be frustratingly complex to work with.

***EDIT*** Another minor problem which is causing the `permButton` to misbehave.

In your button creation code you have:
`permButton.setActionCommand("Perm");`

In your action listener you have: `if (e.getActionCommand().equals("perm"))`

As written your `ActionListener` will never get invoked when `permButton` gets pressed...  Either switch to `equalsIgnoreCase` or define a constant rather than using string literals.

I find adding colored borders to be very helpful when doing layout work.  Here's a quick example of how to do this:

```
npermField.setBounds(23, 50, 60, 20);
add(npermField);
nchooseField.setBounds(230, 50, 60, 20);

// add a border to make the component easier to see during layout.
npermField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE));

add(nchooseField);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've been struggling with the gridlayout unfortunately.  I understand why it would be useful in this instance.

Comment: Doing anything beyond a trivial layout in Swing is somewhat painful in my opinion...  NetBeans has a [Visual GUI builder](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) which would handle all the layout for you (I believe it uses SpringLayout under the hood).  Is that something you could use here?

Comment: Possibly.  Though I followed Netbean's tutorial for a simple Celsius conversion program and it wrote like 300 lines of code.  In class we did a celsius converter and it wasn't nearly as big.  I feel like NetBeans writes a lot of redundant code.  I do like the idea of it though. I gotta play around with it more

Answer (score 0):

If you like your ButtonListener class the way it is (I don't; will comment about it after the main issue), you can simply reword the buttons' setup:

```
.
.
.
add(permButton);
permButton.add(PnrLabel);
// Action Listener for permbutton
permButton.setActionCommand("Perm");
permButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
.
.
.
```

(and likewise for the other buttons).

See? There is no need to add an ActionListener more than once AND also no need to add an ActionListener *in order* to add the real ActionListener.

The way your application was:

1. it didn't work on the first button press (since only then the correct listener is set up);
2. after the first button press, each new press would add another listener, eventually producing unexpected results (I didn't analyzed it thoroughly, and frankly I will not).

**About the ButtonListener**

Roughly speaking, your class does:

```
if (typeA) {
  doActionA();
} else if (typeB) {
  doActionB();
} else if (typeC) {
  doActionC();
}
```

You could simply create 3 separate ActionListeners, each doing just one thing (either doActionA(), or B or C), without ifs. Then set up each button with only the appropriate ActionListener. This way you could also remove the lines `setActionCommand(type);`, since they would become useless.

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking now that you mention it.  Hmmm.. should I just have the Permutation();  and Combination();  methods inside there?    I guess i gotta assign buttonListeners somewhere else

Comment: Made some changes. Got rid of that and called the button listener lower in the class.  Still have issues with the insides of the GUI disappeared when i try to calculate.  hmmm.

Comment: You only need to assign ``ActionListener``s once (ok, you can theoretically assign and remove ``ActionListener``s on the fly... it is just unusual to do this, and in your case completely pointless).

Comment: Besides that, those buttons' setup (here: assign ActionListener) should be done outside any ``actionPerformed()`` method. Once you understand this and previous comment's point you are done.

Comment: See also the Jason's answer. You need to correct both issues to get a correctly working GUI.